# jquery adds own events/functions to html elements of choice?

Tags: jquery, events, function, functional-programming

is it possible to add to an element type or maybe a css selection an own event function?

something like:

```
$("a").bind("blub", function() { alert("aaa" + this); });

$("a").get(0).blub();
```

i want define some functions which are only available for some special elements 
eg.:

the <div class="myDivContainer">...</div> should have the function available:

```
$("myDivContainer").get(0).blub();
```

but on maybe:

```
$("myDivSeparator").get(0).blub();
```

this should not work, because it was not defined for it

is this possible?!

Comment: If you're selecting an ID you have to put a # before, so it would be #myDivContainer

Answer (score 5):

You can create custom events with bind and trigger. See for example this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399867/custom-events-in-jquery).

You must use the trigger method to call the custom event:

```
$("a").bind("blub", function() {});
$("a").trigger("blub");
```

Of course you can trigger the "blub" event only for elements that bind has been called before.

If you want to use blub as a method, then you need to modify/extend the jQuery itself.

Comment: don't understand - how i call the binded method?!

Comment: The trigger("blub") calls the binded method. Google for custom events with jQuery. You will find many useful articles.