# How to raise Jquery Events and handle them?

Tags: jquery, events

I have a page with a widget in it. There is no cross scripting. I want to use Jquery events to communicate between the two. How can I raise a jquery event on a div in widget and then catch it in widget and do something with it?

Any examples or code snippets would be really helpful.

Comment: two what? what widget? can you post an example?

Comment: forget about widget. Could you please tell me how can I raise a simple jquery event and then catch it. I think that would suffice. I did some googling and all I found "live", "trigger" and "bind/unbind". But am not clear about what/how they contribute to raising an event and catching it successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get by with the standard events then this is very simple. You bind an event handler to the div in the widget (assume the div has `id="widget"`) thus:

```
$('#widget').bind('click', function(e){
    // your code here runs when widget div receives the click event.
    // e is the W3-standard DOM event, in case you need it, but
    // you're free to ignore it
});
```

then you can trigger that from elsewhere with `$('#widget").click()`. It would be neat to define custom events to do this but that's a bit more advanced. Once you have the basics working you can google "jquery custom events".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399867/custom-events-in-jquery), even if it's not exactly the same it might help you