# New event type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'd like to make a new event type in JavaScript.  Say I have some criteria for when a user `hasAquiredIceCream`, and I'd like to trigger and bind to this event based on the criteria.  How could I make a new event in JavaScript?  I'm using jQuery, so ideally I'd be able to use it with `.trigger('hasAquiredIceCream')` and `.bind('hasAquiredIceCream')`.  I'm assuming a pure JavaScript solution would work with jQuery just fine (it wouldn't need to be a plugin), can this be done?

Comment: See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399867/custom-events-in-jquery and http://api.jquery.com/trigger/. `.trigger()` and `.bind()` support custom events.

Comment: It already works like you described it...

Comment: @felix ahh, I wasn't aware I didn't need to define it first before using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery's `.trigger()`, [you can trigger custom events on any element](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-custom-events-they-will-rock-your-world/) **or** on a JavaScript object.

```
var obj = { id: 0, ... };

$(obj).bind('custom', function(e, arg, ...) { ... });
$(obj).trigger('custom', [arg, ...]);
```

---

Or, using plain JavaScript, implement the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

```
function EventHelper() {
    this.handlers = [];

    this.bind = function(fn) {
        this.handlers.push(fn);
    };

    this.trigger = function(args) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.handlers.length; i++) {
            this.handlers[i].call(this, args);
        }
    };

    return this;
}

var event = new EventHelper();
event.bind(function() { ... });
event.trigger();
```