# Is there an event for when an input gets disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, input

For an input extension script I'm making I need an input to tell me when/if it gets disabled. That is, when it's `disabled` parameter is set.

Is there an event for this?

If not, how would I emulate the behaviour?

Also I'm using jQuery

Comment: What will be disabling the `input`? It is going to be some other part of your script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, any events that you need to latch on to (and aren't user events - *click*, *mouseover* etc.) should be fired programmatically within the code, as opposed to polling the actual DOM, which is the end-representation that your code produces.

DOM mutation events aren't well supported and AFAIK [are being deprecated](http://old.nabble.com/Replacing-DOM-Mutation-Events-td32276529.html).

From the sounds of what you've said, it seems like the best thing to do would be to check whether the `<input>` is disabled upon initiation of your extension/plugin, and then enable plugin/extension users to disable the input via your own API, meaning that you can know when it happens.

A really primitive example would be creating your own `disable` method for jQuery:

```
jQuery.fn.disable = function() {
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).attr('disabled', true).triggerHandler('disable');
    });
};

// E.g.
var input = jQuery('input#foo');
input.bind('disable', function(){ alert('Foo Disabled!'); });
input.disable();
```

You can see that we trigger our own event for each element within the `disable` method. This is just an example though; I don't really suggest this -- try to keep everything under the namespace of your own plugin/extension.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no built-in event like that. Using trigger and bind, however, you can create your own event. [Custom events in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399867/custom-events-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I hope using `.attr()` you can find its disabled or not

Comment: Finding it is not the issue - detecting when it CHANGES is.