# Access $(this) from within anonymous jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to implement a custom "enterKey" event for jQuery:

```
$('selector').enterKey(function(){  
    alert( $(this).val() ) // doesn't work
});
```

i have done something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5689145/1123630
and it works with one exception: i cannot access $(this) from within my anonymous function

Simplified version of what i want:

```
$.fn.test = function( ev ) {
    ev();
}

$('#val').test( function(){
     alert( $(this).val() );   // works well with static text, 
                               //but not with "this" pointer
});
```

Any help would be apreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you call `ev`, `this` will refer to the global object (`window` in browsers). 
[MDN has a nice summary about `this`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

You have to explicitly set `this`, using [`call` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), or just pass the callback to [`each` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$.fn.test = function( ev ) {
    return this.each(ev);
};
```

By using `each`, you make sure that `this` inside the callback you pass only refers to **one** DOM element, just like other callbacks work, like the one you pass to `.click()`.

Otherwise, inside a plugin method, `this` refers to *all selected elements*. So this would be **wrong** (or at least different from typical jQuery callbacks):

```
$.fn.test = function( ev ) {
    ev.call(this);
    return this;
};
```

On the other side, this would be OK as well, but is unnecessarily verbose:

```
$.fn.test = function( ev ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        ev.call(this);
    });
};
```

Though you have to do this if you wanted to pass custom arguments to your callback (`ev`), otherwise `ev` receives the same arguments as the `each` callback.

Comment: Thanks. I'm amazed how I missed that.