# How to handle custom events between HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have a html file. i am calling a function in some javascript file from the html file. I want to dispatch the event from the js file and want to return the control back. i want to send the control back when i want. Can anyone please help me on how  can i handle custom events in html and javascript.

Regards,
Daksh

Comment: At least provide some code. Otherwise your question doesn't explain itself!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you'd like to achieve. Some code would be a help. If you're convinced that you need custom events, you can read about it [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Event/CustomEvent).

If you use jQuery check [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399867/custom-events-in-jquery).

Comment: This isn't really an answer is it ? Such statements belong as a comment.

Comment: Partially it's an answer. But you're right, it would be more appropriate to add it as a comment.

Comment: basically i want to call some web services in the js class and i want to send control back to the html when the data is created. i am calling the services in js class on click of a button. i want to show some controls in the html when the data is created. for that i want to dispatch an event from the js class and listen it in a function in html

Comment: @Daksh Could you write an example on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) how you handle click on a button and retrieve data from web service? Defaults, all this operation are asynchronous so the control is always returned to HTML. Maybe I misunderstand you and you'd like to present some information that data is being created and after the data is ready just hide this info and display previous content?