# jcarousel events binding - events syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

The documentation of jcarousel specifies possible `create` event for jcarousel object, however when binding to it the following name is used `jcarousel:create`. What is this syntax?

My understanding is that the event name is preceded by namespace, however I haven't encountered this syntax before. jQuery's syntax for namespaces is different and uses dot as a separator between namespace and event name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a syntax for the jcarousel that is specifically created by those who wrote jcarousel. However the syntax used appears like it was created as a namespace to avoid conflicts with other plugins.

The example used in the [documentation for create](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/events.html#create) states that whatever is contained in the event handler will be run when the carousel is created.

**Example Code:**

```
$('.jcarousel').on('jcarousel:create', function(event, carousel) {
    // "this" refers to the root element
    // "carousel" is the jCarousel instance
});
```

It is possible to create custom events in jQuery this is done using trigger and bind. 
See [Custom events in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399867/custom-events-in-jquery)

In the [documentation of jcarousel](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/blob/9f669a1d751321270a3a2b294ce71b688b98d47a/docs/reference/events.md) it says that "Some events are triggered from the constructor, so you have to bind to the events **before** you initialize the plugin."

In the core.js file of jcarousel it has a function called _trigger. When this is called it triggers specific events. Do take note that in the code it creates an event object using the [`$.Event()`](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) function passing in the name of the event as `(pluginName + ':' + type).toLowerCase()`.This creates an event object with a name such as jcarousel:create. It uses the created event object to trigger that name of event which calls the appropriate event handler.

Here is the code that gets called by the constructor:

```
        _trigger: function(type, element, data) {
            var event,
                defaultPrevented = false;

            data = [this].concat(data || []);

            (element || this._element).each(function() {
                event = $.Event((pluginName + ':' + type).toLowerCase());

                $(this).trigger(event, data);

                if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                    defaultPrevented = true;
                }
            });

            return !defaultPrevented;
        }
```