# Can we name an event handler in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I was messing around with jQuery and event handlers, when I noticed this:

[image]

That uses jQuery, and without it:

[image]

How does the popup get a bar saying jQuery? Do browsers have integrated jQuery support to detect that? Or is there some way to name event handlers? I want to have my event display some other text, like how jQuery does.

NOTE: I don't want to use jQuery, as I want to know how jQuery does it.

Comment: You can name *any* function. I don't understand the question. *edit* well I understand parts of it; yes some browser dev tools understand jQuery

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about what you are trying to do, but in Javascript you can always **name** functions

Example:

```
function myEventHandler(event) {
    alert('event handler');
}
```

**myEventHandler** is the name of the function.

Hope this helps a little, 
best, 
  Carsten

Comment: Right, and this is also true for function expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can have custom names for your events if you want. We can use the trigger function for the same purpose.

Suppose you want to raise `myEvent` on `<div id="my_div">`.
We can simply

```
$("#my_div").trigger('myEvent');
```

and have a listener for the event:

```
$("#my_div").on('myEvent', function(event){
    //Event handler
});
```

You can find some good documentation here - 
https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/

And this SO answer covers it thoroughly - 
[Custom events in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399867/custom-events-in-jquery)