# Create "on" event listener on javascript custom object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add `on` event listener for custom object.

For example:

```js
(function () {
    this.EmojiPicker = (function () {
        function EmojiPicker(options) {
            // ...
        }

        EmojiPicker.prototype.test = function () {
            //...
        };

        return EmojiPicker;

    })();
}).call(this);
```

I want to add

```js
let emojiPicker = new EmojiPicker();

emojiPicker.on("change", function () {
    //
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a simple example modified from you code.
See if this can help.

The main idea is to trigger an event by `$(emojiPicker).trigger('change');`,
so that you can receive with `$(emojiPicker).on("change", function () {});`

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function () {
        
        this.EmojiPicker = (function () {
            function EmojiPicker(options) {
                // ...
            }

            EmojiPicker.prototype.test = function () {
                //...
                $(emojiPicker).trigger('change');
            };

            return EmojiPicker;

        })();
        
        
        let emojiPicker = new EmojiPicker();

        $(emojiPicker).on("change", function () {
            alert("triggered");
        });
    }).call(this);
        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</bofy>
</html>
```

More information from [Custom events in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399867/custom-events-in-jquery)